# Compute $A^n$ where $A^2+bA+cI=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a complex matrix such that $$A^2+bA+cI=0,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $b,c\in \mathbb{C}$. I am interested in finding a formula for $A^n$ in terms of $A$ and $I$. The binomial formula  is not giving an answer I think. Maybe using $A^2=-bA-cI$, then $A^3=-bA^2-cA$, etc. But the computation becomes so complicated to find a formula by induction.

Comment: Hint: Apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: If you can diagonalize $A$, $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, then $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$, where $D^n$ is easy.

Comment: It will be on the form $A^n = a_n A + b_n I$. Assume this form and use $A^2 = -bA - cI$ to derive the recursion $a_{n+1} = b_n - ba_n$ and $b_{n+1} = -ca_n$.

Comment: The standard way is to do the polynomial division with rest: $x^n=(x^2+bx+c)q(x)+r(x)$. Then $A^n=r(A)$ and $r$ is of at most first degree.

Comment: That's a good start- but your formula includes $A^2$, not just A.  Just one more step will fix that:  $A^3= bA^2- cA= b(-bA- cI)- cA= (-b^2- c)A- cI$.  Then $A^4= A(A^3)= A((-b^2- c)A- cI)= (-b^2- c)A^2- cA= (-b^2- c)(-bA- cI)- cA= (b^3+ bc- c)A+ (bc+ c^2)I$.  That is, keep replacing $A^2$ with $-bA- cI$

Comment: @A.Γ. I think this is it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** By Long Division

$$X^n=(X^2+bX+c)Q(X)+\alpha X+ \beta$$

Plug in the roots of $X^2+bX+c=0$ to find $\alpha, \beta$.

Then plug in $A$.

**P.S.** If the two roots are equal, then we have
$$X^n=(X-\gamma)^2Q(X)+\alpha X+\beta \tag{*}$$

After puggin in $\gamma$ in $(*)$ you need to differentiate $(*)$ and plug in $\gamma$ again.

This method works even if the polynomial you have has higher degree.

Comment: Took me a minute to see why this gives a closed form. Of course it does, _if_ $b^2\ne 4c$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If $b^2=4ac$ then derivate the relation and plug in the double root ;)

Comment: I was just about to say that. It seems possible we should be more explicit about why this solves the OP's problem: It follows that $A^n=\alpha_n A+\beta_n I$, so a closed form for $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ gives a closed form for $A^n$.

Comment: I will never underestimate the Euclidean Division again :).

Answer (score 0):

You have $$ A^{n+2} = b_nA + c_nI $$

where $b_0 = -b, c_0 = -c$

Multiplying both sides by $A$ gives
$$ A^{n+3} = b_nA^2 + c_n A = b_n(-bA-cI)+c_nA = (c_n-bb_n)A - cb_nI $$

therefore
$$ b_{n+1} = -bb_n + c_n, \ c_{n+1} = -cb_n $$

You may find an implicit relation by solving the linear system
$$ \left(\matrix{b_n\\c_n}\right)=M^n\left(\matrix{-b\\-c}\right) $$

where
$$ M = \left(\matrix{-b&c\\-c&0}\right) $$

then we have the characteristic
$$ \lambda^2 + b\lambda + c^2 = 0 $$

The two eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, where $b = -(\lambda_1+\lambda_2), c^2 = \lambda_1\lambda_2$

The eigenvectors are
$$ \vec{v_1} = \left(\matrix{-\lambda_1\\c}\right), \ 
\vec{v_2} = \left(\matrix{-\lambda_2\\c}\right) $$

Thus
$$ M^n\left(\matrix{-b\\-c}\right) = -M^n(\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}) = -{\lambda_1}^n\ \vec{v_1} - {\lambda_2}^n\ \vec{v_2} $$

---

If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ then we have the generalized eigenvectors
$$ \vec{v_1} = \lambda \left(\matrix{-1\\1}\right), \ \vec{v_2} = \left(\matrix{-2\\1}\right) $$

Then 
$$ M^n\left(\matrix{2\lambda\\-\lambda}\right) = -M^n \lambda \vec{v_2} = \lambda^{n+1}\vec{v_2} + n\lambda^n \vec{v_1} $$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $m(\lambda)=\lambda^2+b\lambda +c$ annihilates $A$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
      (A+(\mu+b)I)(A-\mu I)&=A^2+bA-\mu(\mu+b)I\\
           &= -(\mu^2+b\mu+c)I \\
     (A-\mu I)^{-1}&=-\frac{1}{\mu^2+b\mu +c}(A+(\mu+b)I).
\end{align}
Using a little Complex Analysis by integrating in $\mu$ around both zeros of $\mu^2+b\mu +c$ gives
$$
         f(A)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}f(\mu)(\mu I-A)^{-1}d\mu.
$$
The zeroes of $\mu^2+b\mu +c$ are $-b/2\pm \sqrt{b^2/4-c}$ denoting these roots by $r_1,r_2$ gives an integral
$$
    f(A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}f(\mu)\frac{1}{(\mu-r_1)(\mu-r_2)}(A+(\mu+b)I)d\mu \\
   = f(r_1)\frac{1}{r_1-r_2}(A+(r_1+b)I)+f(r_2)\frac{1}{r_2-r_1}(A+(r_2+b)I) \\
   = \frac{f(r_1)-f(r_2)}{r_1-r_2}(A+bI)+\frac{r_1f(r_1)-r_2f(r_2)}{r_1-r_2}I.
$$
So, for example,
$$
    A^{n} = \frac{r_1^n-r_2^n}{r_1-r_2}(A+bI)+\frac{r_1^{n+1}-r_2^{n+2}}{r_1-r_2}I.
$$

Comment: Good answer. Moreover, when $r_1=r_2$, you obtain the result by continuity.

Comment: @loupblanc : Thanks. Complex Analysis provides such a concise solution that I thought it was worth posting, even though I didn't figure it would be chosen as the solution. :)